# React Native Upgrade 0.65. What happens to the older non-supported iOS10 devices

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone, react-native

We want to upgrade our app (used by 1000s of devices) to the latest React Native version. Upon checking the Changelogs, FB has removed support for iOS10 when upgrading to RN 0.65. My question is what would happen to the older devices like iPhone 5c etc. that can only run iOS10?

Will they be able to see the app in the App Store?
Will they be able to download the app updates in future?
Any other information that can be useful here.
Thanks for your help in advance.